# Ubuntu has been blocked by the current security policy

Tags: 12.04, 14.04, boot, bios

I have upgraded my Ubuntu from 12.04 to 14.04. On the beginning, I had some troubles entering my laptop, but after 2-3 reboots it got working. Anyway, I have used my new 14.04 version fine, and since this mourning I cannot enter my laptop (I have Dell Inspiron 17R - the worst piece of crap I have ever bought, I always have problems with Ubuntu with this laptop). All I can see is [this](https://pbs.twimg.com/media/B1GzoSrIEAAAOGW.jpg:large) message:

```
Ubuntu has been blocked by the current security policy
```

Also, after I click "OK", my laptop cannot boot, it has the message:

```
Checking media [Fail]
```

followed by:

```
No Boot Device Found. Press any key to reboot the machine
```

How can I solve this problem? I have very important files on my laptop that I don't want to be lost. Any way I can save my files at least?

Thank you very much in advance for your help.

Answer (score 5):

I just installed Ubuntu-14.01.1 on a Dell Inspiron 15-5547 (Should be close if not the same as your 17R).

Boot in the BIOS (press **F2** when the Dell logo appears after powering up), go into the "Boot" menu and change "Secure Boot Mode" to [Disabled]; **F10** to "Save and Exit" and you should be able to load Ubuntu.